# Alternative to many case switch statement in C

Tags: c, arduino, switch-statement

I have a 8 bit byte that represents the states of 8 physical switches. I need to do something different for each permutation of switches being on and off. My first idea was to write a 256 case switch statement, but it quickly became tedious to type.

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: I should have been a bit clearer on the functions. I have 8 buttons that each do one thing. I need to be able to detect if multiple switches are pressed at once so I can run both functions at the same time.

Comment: Call table of function pointers?

Comment: *"it quickly became tedious to type*" not as tedious as implementing every switch state. But the lookup table method will execute faster.

Comment: Are you really implementing 256 different functions, or are some single or groups of switches being ganged together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array of function pointers. Be careful to index it by a positive value - a `char`  might be signed. Whether this is any more tedious than using a `switch` statement is arguable - but execution will certainly be quicker.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// prototypes
int func00(void);
int func01(void);
...
int funcFF(void);

// array of function pointers
int (*funcarry[256])(void) = {
    func00, func01, ..., funcFF
};

// call one function
int main(void){
    unsigned char switchstate = 0x01;
    int res = (*funcarry[switchstate])();
    printf ("Function returned %02X\n", res);
    return 0;
}

// the functions
int func00(void) {
    return 0x00;
}
int func01(void) {
    return 0x01;
}
...
int funcFF(void) {
    return 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: For _not_ using `char` which may be signed, +1

Comment: what are the protoypes for? can I not just define the functions.

Comment: I had your answer checked, but I realized that I had been unclear in my original question about the number of functions. Still thanks for the information.

Comment: Why should the execution be quicker? In such a scenario, you would get a jumptable out of `switch`, which might be even a tiny bit faster than your current approach as it saves a function invocation.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it answered my original question. after some more research, I think my specific problem may be better solved by using binary arithmetic. Thanks for the quick and concise answer

Comment: @a3f OP said "256 case switch statement, but it quickly became tedious to type", that reads to me like an average of 128 conditionals to check before hitting the matching case. That is why execution would be **far** quicker using a lookup table of functions, unless perhaps there is an optimising compiler which might rewrite the code. That might be the case these days, but embedded compilers I have used barely optimised anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an array of functions and use the byte as an index in the array and correspondingly call the function in the given position in the array.

Comment: Can you show how OP would do that? At least mention `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Weather Vane  Op asks about the idea not about some details.

Comment: He asked for a better way - you've just repeated the comments. It's not an answer.

Comment: @Weather Vane  I have nothing repeated. I have provided my answer.