# What is the difference between declarations: void (*allocators[])(size_t) and void* allocators[] ?

Tags: c

40 different allocation functions give 40 different call sites

```
void f00(size_t sz) { void* ptr = malloc(sz); free(ptr); }
void f01(size_t sz) { void* ptr = malloc(sz); free(ptr); }
...
void f39(size_t sz) { void* ptr = malloc(sz); free(ptr); }
```

An array of those allocation functions. How I need to define?

like this: why `(size_t)` ?:

```
  void (*allocators[])(size_t) = { &f00, &f01, ... , &f39 };
```

or

```
  void* allocators[] = { &f00, &f01, ... , &f39 };
```

and what the difference between this two declarations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How define an array of function pointers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488608/how-define-an-array-of-function-pointers-in-c)

Comment: Please see my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310161/alternative-to-many-case-switch-statement-in-c/29310574#29310574

Comment: Already answered, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309859/how-to-define-an-array-of-functions-in-c

Comment: OP also asked *why `(size_t)` ?* Because that is the argument of the functions.

Comment: @WeatherVane this is a rule? Can I use the second declaration?

Comment: Please have a read through the many previous answers!

Comment: @WeatherVane This is a different question because I asked why we need to put (size_t) and what the difference between two declarations

Comment: Don't you think both of your questions have been answered here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is correct. In first declaration no need of `&` in intializers. It should be

```
 void (*allocators[])(size_t) = { f00, f01, ... , f39 };
```

It declares `allocators` as an array of pointers to function that return nothing and expects an argument of `size_t` type.
`(size_t)` informs the compiler that all functions expects an argument of this type.

Second is wrong because it declares an array of pointers to `void`.

Comment: They are not both wrong. The version with `&f00, &f01, ...` is correct and is equivalent to your answer. You can argue that `&` is redundant, but that doesn't make it *wrong*.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves; Apologies. I was out of mind then. You are right.

Comment: Why (size_t) in the first variant? I mean  void (*allocators[])(size_t)

Comment: The first is correct. The second is wrong (you switched it in your answer).

Comment: @Anatoly Because that's what the functions expect as an argument.

Comment: @Anatoly Because someone wrote them that way. If you want to declare a pointer to a function receiving `X`, then you'll have to specify `X` as part of the pointer declaration, don't you agree?

Comment: Because it's the function argument you declared for every function in the array, and the compiler needs to know what arguments are needed when one of the functions in the array is called.